# Difficulty Constructing Binary Tree from Array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, binary-tree, bsp-tree

I am trying to build a binary tree from an unsorted float array for an assignment, but I cannot quite figure it out. My goal is to send the unsorted array `xdata` of size `ndata` to the function `build_tree()`, which creates a new node using the function create_node(). In the case that the array size is greater than 1, it will call the function `paritition_data()` (which works fine, but I've placed it at the bottom of the question for reference), which will swap the order of array values so that all values less than `mid` fall on its left, and greater values to its right. The function returns `nleft`, the number of values on the left of `mid`. I then want to recursively call `partition_data()` to create new `left` and `right` child nodes. I think it is at this step that my program seems to fail, and despite it compiling, the program seems to recursively call `partition_data()` infinitely, and I'm not sure why. I appreciate any help.

```
typedef struct treenode_struct {
  int n;
  float data;
  struct treenode_struct *left, *right;
} treenode;

treenode *create_node( ) {
  treenode *node;

  node = malloc(sizeof(treenode));
  if (node == NULL) {
    printf("Allocate Failed");
    exit(-1);
  }
  node->n = 0;
  node->right = NULL;
  node->left = NULL;

  tree_nodes++;

  return node;
}

treenode *build_tree( float xdata[], int ndata, float xmin, float xmax ) {
  treenode *node;
  int nleft;
  float mid = (xmin+xmax)/2.;

  node = create_node();
  node->n = ndata;
  if (ndata == 1) {  // Add code for this case
    node->data = xdata[0]; 
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
  }
  if (ndata == 0){
    printf("Allocate failed\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
 // More than one data point: use partition function
  if (ndata > 1) {
    nleft = partition_data(xdata,ndata,mid);
    int nright = ndata-nleft;

    // Add code to make a left child
    if(nleft != 0){
      node->left=build_tree(xdata,nleft,xmin,xdata[nleft-1]);
    }
    else{
      node->left = NULL;
    }

    // Add code to make a right child
    if(nright != 0){
      node->right=build_tree(xdata,nright,xdata[nleft],xmax);
    }
    else{
      node->right = NULL;
    }
    return node;
  }
}

int tree_nodes;

int main() {
  const int ndata = 16;
  float xdata[] = { 0.963,  0.003, 0.0251, 0.353, 0.667, 0.838, 0.335, 0.915,
            0.796, 0.833, 0.345, 0.871, 0.089, 0.888, 0.701, 0.735 };
  int i;
  float xmiddle = 0.5;
  printf("Input data:\n");
  for (i=0;i<ndata;i++) printf("%f ",xdata[i]);
  printf("\n");

 treenode *tree_root;
  float tree_xmin, tree_xmax;
  tree_nodes = 0;

  tree_xmin = 0;
  tree_xmax = 1;
  tree_root = build_tree( xdata, ndata, tree_xmin, tree_xmax );
  printf("Tree Built: nodes %d\n",tree_nodes);

  printf("Tree Ordered data:\n");
  for (i=0;i<ndata;i++) printf("%f ",xdata[i]);
  printf("\n\n");
}
```

Here is `partition_data()`:

```
int partition_data( float xdata[], int ndata, float xmiddle ) {

  // Your code goes here
  int left = 0;
  int right = ndata-1;
  float temp;
  while(left < ndata){  //left loop
    if(xdata[left] < xmiddle){
      if(left == right){
    return left+1;
    break;
      }//DONE
      left = left + 1;
    }
    else{
      while(right<ndata){ //right loop, search for swappable Xright
    if(xdata[right] >= xmiddle){//X[right] is greater than/equal to xmiddle
      if(left == right){
        return left;
        break;
      }
      right=right-1;
    }
    else{ //found X[right] to swap
      temp = xdata[left];
      xdata[left] = xdata[right];//swap
      xdata[right]=temp;
      right = right-1;
      if(left == right) {
        return left+1;
        break;
      }
      left=left+1;
      break;
    }
    break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is your `mid` variable supposed to represent?? The middle of your boundary or the middle of your array??

Comment: `mid` represents the middle of the range of values in the array, it's calculated from the `xmin` and `xmax` values sent to `build_tree()`.

Comment: You might be confusing things...I think `mid` should represent the element at the middle of the array

Comment: the idea is that `mid` isn't an element in the array, it represents the border across which elements are swapped on either side so that elements less than `mid` are on its left, and those greater are on its right. I included the partitioning function to better explain how it works.

Comment: I think I see where your recursion comes from ... but as I don't see why `mid` is not the middle element of the array and why `node->n = ndata;` I can't say if I'm correct or not

Comment: Since `mid` is calculated from finding the value halfway between `xmin` and `xmax` (which mark the minimum and maximum values of all values contained at each node), the resultant value for `mid` is not an element on the array. It is calculated to continuously divide the elements at each node in half so that they can be sent to a child node depending on where the partition function sorts them in relation to `mid`. `node->n = ndata` is intended to assign the number of values at a node array (`ndata`) to `n`, which is part of the `treenode` struct. I added the `treenode` definition to my question

Comment: So only your `treenode`s at the bottom of your tree will contain your elements of the array??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursion problem is caused by the creation of your right node.
You create the right node with this code:

```
// Add code to make a right child
if(nright != 0){
  node->right=build_tree(xdata,nright,xdata[nleft],xmax);
}
else{
  node->right = NULL;
}
```

Now if you look at your `build_tree` function what you have is:

```
treenode *build_tree( float xdata[], int ndata, float xmin, float xmax )
```

Let's interprete it as:

> create a tree from the array `xdata[]` where all elements are greater than `xmin` and less than `xmax`

Now don't see `xdata[]` as *array* `xdata[]` but see `xdata` as the *pointer to the first element I have to process*. This will (hopefully) help you understand it a little bit (and is actually what it is, it is just a pointer).
In your code to create the right node you use:

```
 node->right=build_tree(xdata,nright,xdata[nleft],xmax);
```

but there you actually insert as right node the root of the tree that will be created by processing the data starting at the first element of your array. That's not the slice of the array you want. The slice you want to have in your right node is the right part of the array so the part that starts at index `ndata-nright`. So if you want to change the begin of an array, you just add the index to the pointer of the array. So in your case `xdata + (ndata-nright)` will represent an array that starts at element `ndata-nright` (or pointer to that element). So you should have:

```
  node->right=build_tree(xdata + (ndata-nright),mid,xdata[nleft],xmax);
```

to create your right node!

Comment: Thank you for your help! That is part of the solution, I also needed to use `mid` for the `xmax` argument in the left child `build_tree` call, as well as for the `xmin` argument in the right child call.

Comment: ooh ok. I'm glad it helped though. My apologies, as you had seen in the comments I was a little bit confused about the `mid`. I'll add that in my answer.